# UDP packet loss - but no packets shown as dropped due anywhere?

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, packet, packet-loss

For a networking test, I am sending 5 megabytes worth of small datagrams (with a UDP payload size of 50 bytes each without headers) and testing how fast the server can receive all ~100000 packets.

The pseudo-code is as shown below:

*Server (recv as fast as possible, >50mbps download):*

```
bind("20.30.40.50", 5000)

while (true)
    recv_next_udp() // negligible overhead
    if (count++ % 100000 == 0)
        break

print "100000 * 50 bytes = 5 megabytes recv"
```

*Client (send as fast as possible, >20mbps upload):*

```
while (true)
    send_udp_now("20.30.40.50", 5000)
    if (count++ % 100000 == 0)
        break

print "100000 * 50 bytes = 5 megabytes sent"
```

If I send to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`: I receive all datagrams and both complete with their messages as expected.
If I bind and send to a public address: I only receive ~40% of the datagrams (around 40000 of them) and lose the other ~60%.

**Q:** If the client says that all datagrams were sent, `netstat -s` shows that all datagrams were sent and none dropped, and the server shows that no datagrams were lost or dropped due to internal buffers or slow reads: how do I find the reason and location of the packet loss?

It is not an issue with a maxed-out operating system buffer according to `netstat` and I have a hard time believing that routers and switches have less than a 5 megabyte buffer. If I slow down the sends and add a short delay between each send, there is no packet loss.

Comment: With no information about your network setup between the client and server, this is impossible to answer, but switches may be configured to assume latency is more important than bandwidth or reliability for UDP, so never buffer it at all -- just forward if possible and drop if there's congestion.

Comment: Directly connected to home routers with no control of the route in between. No switches present on our sides.